# Youtube GData API : Retrieving public statistics

Tags: youtube, gdata

On YouTube now there is a show video statistics button which shows the statistics of video like view count over time and demography .

I have looked through the YouTube api but I didn't seem to find a way to retrieve this data.
The closest I could come to was http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_insight.html but this is for particular user . I wished to get data available in public .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes like mad_scientist said, the public insights for a video are not provided via the API

https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_insight

"YouTube Insight, an analytics and reporting engine, provides viewing statistics, popularity metrics and demographic information for videos and channels.

```
A video entry contains a link to Insight data if the authenticated user retrieving the entry owns the video.

A profile entry contains a link to Insight data for the channel if the authenticated user is retrieving his or her own profile."
```

If you want to get likes and dislikes, and works with c#, you can use this code:

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/youtube-api-gdata/UBbiyE3Cw5M

:)

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, the public insights for a video are not provided via the API (and I´m pretty sure they won´t add id, but maybe there is a small chance they´ll implement this in the new analytics API). If you want to query the statics for your own video, you could use the insights API[Insights API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_insight). For all other videos, you could screen-scrape/parse the insights out of the xml/CDATA-Response with this link

http://www.youtube.com/insight_ajax?action_get_statistics_and_data=1&v=*YOURVIDEOID*

You should use a parser which is capable of parsing broken html, like lxml or BeautifulSoup for python.

Answer (score 1):

Now this service is available, but now he need a token for download the file insight ajax.xml with all data. because if a call the service
http://www.youtube.com/insight_ajax?action_get_statistics_and_data=1&v=MYVIDEOID
the response is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root><return_code>
<![CDATA[1]]>
</return_code>
<error_message>
<![CDATA[The request is not valid.]]>
</error_message></root>
```

the POST call has this fotmat :

```
Parameters 
application/x-www-form-urlencoded
session_token   1UEcRYZx-I3xifChIhm5QFOKxfJ8MTM3MjI1MjY3OUAxMzcyMTY2Mjc5
Source
session_token=1UEcRYZx-I3xifChIhm5QFOKxfJ8MTM3MjI1MjY3OUAxMzcyMTY2Mjc5
```