# I want the total amount of youtube plays

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

Hey all wondering if i can use youtube api's to get the TOTAL number of youtube plays - wondering if they offer this statistic to public through their API's.

I want to get the live count to every few seconds.

Comment: Updated my answer to further show an working example,

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Youtube API's web page. At a first glande I've seen this [link](https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/v1/).

In there you'll find `metrics` as mandatory parameter of the request. In such parameter you may specify which metrics you want to retrieve (for instance, `views`, `likes`, `dislikes`). Take also a look at the further descriptions of `metrics` in this [link](https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/v1/dimsmets/mets).

Answer (score 0):

**Working jQuery Example:** Get view count and video title (Created quickly by me)

**Example Fiddle URL:**  http://jsfiddle.net/mu9wwmza/

**Working Source:** Below....

```
<input value="CplTXmbJj3g" type="text" id="txtVidID" />
<input type='button' onclick="getViewsFromYT()" value="Query Video Stats" />
<script>
    function getViewsFromYT() {
        var sURL = "https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/" + $("#txtVidID").val() + "?v=2&alt=json";
        $.getJSON( sURL, function( data ) {
            var sTitle = data.entry['media$group']['media$title']['$t'];
            var iCount = data.entry['yt$statistics'].viewCount;
            alert(iCount + " views for : " + sTitle);        

        });
    }
<script>
```

**What does it do??** Well simply it will grab the contents of a URL like [THIS](https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/CplTXmbJj3g?v=2&alt=json) and will then grab the name and view variables to alert them back to the user.

**EDIT - PER CHANNEL**
something like this url:https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=statistics&forUsername=ExplosmEntertainment&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

Will give you a response of something like this:

```
{
 "kind": "youtube#channelListResponse",
 "etag": "\"OZTVc5giYjExcw9vrLsdrwdwB4c/wFb6RBgqjeO72V-0OhHhka5ADvI\"",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 1,
  "resultsPerPage": 5
 },
 "items": [
  {

   "kind": "youtube#channel",
   "etag": "\"OZTVc5giYjExcw9vrLsdrwdwB4c/iOZxog5cbjPLsV37DfO_fkODBDk\"",
   "id": "UCWXCrItCF6ZgXrdozUS-Idw",
   "statistics": {
    "viewCount": "594362694",
    "commentCount": "923",
    "subscriberCount": "3976887",
    "hiddenSubscriberCount": false,
    "videoCount": "121"
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

You can test this with their v3 API 
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list#try-it

---

A quick google returned this as the first result: https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_insight

In the section **Insight reports and their contents** it shows the **Views** which can be specified to a time frame, so you would simply apply this from the date you uploaded the video to the current date/time.

Second google result was: [How to get number of video views with YouTube API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3331176/how-to-get-number-of-video-views-with-youtube-api)

```
<?php
  $video_ID = 'your-video-ID';
  $JSON = file_get_contents("https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/{$video_ID}?v=2&alt=json");
  $JSON_Data = json_decode($JSON);
  $views = $JSON_Data->{'entry'}->{'yt$statistics'}->{'viewCount'};
  echo $views;
?>
```

And this link [Retrieve public statistics of video via youtube api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18530618/retrieve-public-statistics-of-video-via-youtube-api) refers to v3, but i would need to setup a video to test it further... Should give you a starting point

Comment: Hey there - this is for a single youtube video - i'm looking for all the views from all videos posted on youtube. I've searched through the api's & I understand that I can get total views from an entire channel.

Comment: In that case you want something like this: https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=statistics&forUsername=ExplosmEntertainment&key={YOUR_API_KEY} but just noting you did not mention in your question relating to a channel.. So the assumption in this case is per video.