# How to retrieve like/dislike/view count from Youtube?

Tags: python, youtube, youtube-api

I want to get some minimal statistic Information from a youtube-video for "**like**", "**dislike**", "**view**" **count**. However, i got so far, that i can retrieve the JSON for the Videoinformation, but there is none of the above mentioned information.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18530618/retrieve-public-statistics-of-video-via-youtube-api

Comment: Not related to Python at all.

Comment: Sorry, i didn't mean to add python as a tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, without using the Google API and and doing any O-AUTH, i am just parsing the website and getting **like** count and **title**.

import requests
    import re

```
filesInChannel = [
"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PYuNBFdwK7k",
"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-Ox9MvottBI"
]

def getStats(link):
    page = requests.get(link)
    likes = re.search("with (\d*.\d*.\d*)", page.text).group(1)
    title = re.search("property=\"og:title\" content=\"([^\n]*)", page.text).group(1)
    return (likes, title)


for link in filesInChannel:
    stats = getStats(link)
    print stats[0].encode("utf-8") + " " + stats[1].encode("utf-8")
```

Comment: To add more information, you just have to add more regex search statements

Comment: Given I do not know the video Id, If I want to get views by simply creating search queries, I get a list of options to choose from. Can that window be sorted by Views so that I can filter the highest view?

Comment: how many urls can you scrap with this method? is it possible to use it for thousands of videos?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [videos/getRating](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/getRating)

> Valid values for this property are:
>
> - dislike
> - like
> - none
> - unspecified

Example:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos/getRating?id=test>&key=<key>
```

Comment: will this only work when i am the admin of the video?

Comment: Yes it requires authentication

Comment: @user1767754 they mean an authentication key. you can create one at google developers

Answer (score 0):

The following query using the `youtubeAnalytics.reports.query` portion of the YouTube Analytics API v1 will return the count of views, likes, and dislike counts for the channel and time span specified:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/analytics/v1/reports?ids=channel=={CHANNEL_ID}&start-date=2018-02-18&end-date=2018-03-26&metrics=views,likes,dislikes&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

Running the query does require the user to be authorized.  You can use the [APIs Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/?hl=en_US#p/youtubeAnalytics/v1/youtubeAnalytics.reports.query) to test and modify the above query.